# How to install pydataset using conda command, or Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.7, python-3.8, anaconda3

I want to install pydataset package in anaconda, below pip command installs it on python 2.7, but I have python 3.7 for Jupyter notebook. How to install pydataset using conda command?

```
pip install pydataset
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can issue that same command inside of an [anaconda prompt](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/#open-anaconda-prompt).

See [here](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-conda-and-pip):

> Occasionally a package is needed which is not available as a conda
>   package but is available on PyPI and can be installed with pip. In
>   these cases, it makes sense to try to use both conda and pip.